# how to compare datastorage saved items with user input in js using dom or jquery

Tags: javascript, dom, local-storage

I managed to create a signup form and its saving in local storage fine. now I want to create the signin form, I am parsing in from local storage and then comparing but its not working, I dunno whats wrong with my code, any tips ?

````
const signup = () => {
  let formData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("formData")) || [];

  let exist =
    formData.length &&
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("formData")).some(
      (data) =>
        data.email.toLowerCase() == document.getElementById("email") &&
        data.password.toLowerCase() == document.getElementById("password").value
    );

  if (!exist) {
    formData.push({
      // e.preventDefault();    // to stop page reload
      email: document.getElementById("email").value,
      pwd: document.getElementById("password").value,
      pwd2: document.getElementById("password2").value,
    });

    localStorage.setItem("formData", JSON.stringify(formData));
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("formData"));
  }

const signin = () => {

    
  let formData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("formData")) || [];
  let exist =
    formData.length &&
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("formData")).some(
      (data) =>
        data.email == document.getElementById("signEmail").value &&
        data.password == document.getElementById("signinPassword").value
    );
    if (exist == true) {
        isLogged=true;
        console.log("You are loged in."); 
      }
    }
    ```
    why do we save it this way     || [];  ?
````

Answer (score 0):

```
const signin = () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem("formData")) {
    // as long as you are getting items from the local storage... do..

    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("formData")).forEach((data) => {
      let x = document.getElementById("signEmail").value;
      let z = document.getElementById("signinPassword").value;
      console.log(x, z);
      if (data.email == x && data.pwd == z) {
        console.log("You are LOGGED");
      }
    });
  }
};
```

I was comparing form data with undefined because i did not use the correct key which i used to store the data in the localStorage.